# Getting the page scrollTop value in elm

Tags: javascript, scroll, elm

I have started playing around with the language Elm. I am making a basic web page and I would like to make my nav bar stick to the top when scrolling.

I would like to be able to make my model react to the distance scrolled down from the top of the page.

I have two problems:

1. How to access this variable with Javascript? Ideally I would like
   something like JQuery's `$(window).scrollTop()` but without JQuery
2. How to pass this value back to Elm? Do I have to set up a port?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to set up a port in elm to act as a signal which provides the scrollTop distance. Since we're going to provide that value from javascript, you only need to declare the port function signature:

```elm
port scrollTop : Signal Int
```

On its own, that will do nothing. You have to edit the javascript which initiates your elm application to provide values for that signal. Here's the javascript to set that up:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = Elm.fullscreen(Elm.Main, {
  scrollTop: document.body.scrollTop
});

window.onscroll = function () {
  app.ports.scrollTop.send(document.body.scrollTop);
};
</script>
```

Two things to note: You need an initial value for the scrollTop signal. That's what I'm sending in as the second parameter to `Elm.fullscreen()`. This guarantees that, when your app loads, it will start off with the correct scrollTop value right away. The `window.onscroll` handler then sends new scrollTop values to that signal any time the window is scrolled.

To test this out, we can write a simple little debugging port that will change the browser title bar to show the current scrollTop value. Add this to the elm file:

```elm
port title : Signal String
port title =
  Signal.map toString scrollTop
```

Lastly, for our test, we just need a tall page. This should do the trick:

```elm
main =
  let
    line n =
      div [] [ text <| "Line #" ++ (toString n) ]
  in
    div []
      <| List.map line [0..100]
```

I have the provided the full code here: [Main.elm](https://gist.github.com/freakingawesome/547bd36434868987bc4d) and [scroll-test.html](https://gist.github.com/freakingawesome/8baa9c0c83f6f9dbbfe5). You can compile that locally, then watch the title bar change as you scroll up and down on the page.