# Infinite scroll in Elm

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll, elm

I am building a simple application in Elm that show just a list of divs one under the other, and I would like to add infinite scroll functionality, to add new content every time the last div of the page appears in the viewport.

Is there a way in Elm to know when a div appears in the viewport? As an alternative, in there a way to track, as a signal, the mouse scroll event?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is currently no Elm support for scroll events, so you'll have to resort to using ports. Here's a simple example.

We need a javascript function to tell us whether the last element in the list is in the view port. We can take the `isElementInViewport` code from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433) (copied here for future reference):

```js
function isElementInViewport (el) {
    //special bonus for those using jQuery
    if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
    }

    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
    );
}
```

Let's say your HTML looks something like this:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

Your Elm code could have a port acting as a signal to tell us whether the last item is visible.

```elm
port lastItemVisible : Signal Bool
```

Now you need to wire up the port code on the Javascript side of things. This code will listen to the `window.onscroll` event, then check to see if the last item inside the `.wrapper` div is visible, and send the appropriate signal.

```js
var app = Elm.fullscreen(Elm.Main, {
  lastItemVisible: false
});

window.onscroll = function () {
  var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0];
  var lastItem = wrapper.childNodes[wrapper.childNodes.length - 1];

  if (isElementInViewport(lastItem)) {
    app.ports.lastItemVisible.send(true);
  } else {
    app.ports.lastItemVisible.send(false);
  }
};
```

If you instead just wanted a signal for tracking scroll events, [there is a related StackOverflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554652/getting-the-page-scrolltop-value-in-elm#answer-34557333).